# Swift target action

Tags: swift, macos, interface-builder

I'm coming from a C# background and I'm trying to get into Swift and OSX development. When I implement a custom control in .NET I can create events to notify event handlers of things going on in my control.

For example: If I create a control that allows the user to drop files on it, I can fire an event whenever the user drops a file and the event handler can directly handle the dropped file.

Now, I want to implement a `NSControl` derived view. `NSControl` already implements the target-action pattern and provides the `action` action, which I can connect in Interface Builder to some method to handle the action. The `action` action is also available when I right-click the control:

[image]

Now what I want to do is define *another* action (and maybe another later) that can be connected the same way using IB. I looked up the definition of `NSControl` and it shows me the following two lines:

```
weak public var target: AnyObject? 
public var action: Selector
```

But adding similar code to my subclass doesn't to anything in IB (the `@IBDesigable` attribute is set for the class).

I then went on to do define a protocol that can be implemented by some delegate:

```
public protocol SomeDelegate {
    func someDelegateMethod(path: String)
}

@IBDesignable
public final class GreatControl: NSControl {
    public var delegate: SomeDelegate?
```

I can set the delegate in code like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myGreatControl: GreatControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myGreatControl!.delegate = self
}
```

But I'd really like to set the delegate using IB instead of in code.

The question is: I'd prefer the target-action pattern as it is very close to what .NET or other event-driven environments do. How can I implement this so I can connect the actions using IB? If that's not possible, can I somehow make it so at least a delegate can be set through IB instead of code only?

---

PS: When I google for this, there's hardly any information about OSX. There seem to be only IOS developers out here. I'd prefer answers that do not detail how to do things for IOS (unless they work the same for OSX), as I don't develop an IOS app.

Comment: There is the `@IBInspectable` decorator, however it only works for properties like ints, colors. Not sure if action mapping is supported by IB for custom objects/actions.

Comment: @Cristik I actually tried that already and it doesn't do anything. After rephrasing the question I actually found an answer here on SO talking about doing the same thing for IOS views (I actually can't link it right now, I'm at work and don't have the link at hand). The answer was that you *can* implement other targets and actions, but you do have to connect them in code. That would be a shame really...